# How to append items to context data in a ListView?

Tags: django, django-views

I am using a custom mixin in a `ListView` and want to add `values` for a specific `key` (`list`?) to the `context` variable :

```
class MyMixin:
    mylist = ['itemA']

class MyList(MyMixin, ListView):
    mylist = ['item1','item2']

    def get_context_date(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['mylist'].append(self.mylist)
    return context
```

The desired outcome is `mylist = ['itemA', 'item1', 'item2']`

However, this results in a `key_error`. What's the correct approach to append key values to `context`?

Answer (score 4):

`ListView` is to return **list of model instances (or other objects)** retrieved as a result of `get_queryset()` method. Which usually is a `QuerySet` to retrieve some model objects but can be ***any iterable***.

In your example there is no code on how `mylist` attribute should initially appear in the view context.

First, you need to define [get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering) method to return an iterable of required objects.

Or, you can set it at class-level attribute `queryset`, however it might be not very dynamic.

Next, you can define context variable name that will be used to contain the list of data that this view is manipulating - either with `context_object_name` class attribute or in case dynamic name is required for each request - with [get_context_object_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_object_name) method.

Also, class-level `mylist` attribute is ***not available __*** on class instances (accessed as `self) until set in`__init`method. You can access it as a class attribute`MyList.mylist` or simply define on method level as local variable.

```
class MyList(MyMixin, ListView):
    context_object_name "mylist"

    def get_queryset(self):
        # some logic to return required data of this view
        # or simply
        # return ['itemA']
        return SomeModel.objects.all().values_list('name', flat=True)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        mylist = ['item1','item2']
        context['mylist'].append(mylist)
        return context
```